# How to make a SQL table that fits this restriction?

Tags: sql

There are 3 tables: A, B, and C

One A can correspond with multiple B's
and one B can correspond with multiple A's

This is a Many to Many relationship represented by my AB table.

One AB can correspond with multiple C's and one C can correspond with multiple AB's **BUT** only if the AB's corresponding to that single C have different B id's.

What kind of tables and relationships should I use? Do I need the "unique" keyword?

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need the `b_id` in table `c`.  And a foreign key relationship to `ab`.  Then you can have a unique constraint in `abc`.

So, these are the key ideas:

```
create table ab (
    ab_id int primary key,
    a_id int references a(a_id),
    b_id int references b(b_id)
    unique (a_id, b_id)
);

create table abc (,
    abc_id int primary key,
    a_id int,
    b_id int,
    c_id int,
    foreign key (a_id, b_id) references ab(a_id, b_id),
    unique (c_id, b_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

## AB

You create an AB table that will look like AB(A_ID, B_ID), where

- (A_ID, B_ID) is the primary key
- A_ID is a foreign key that references A(ID)
- B_ID is a foreign key that references B(ID)

## ABC

You create an ABC table that will look like (A_ID, B_ID, C_ID) where

- (A_ID, B_ID, C_ID) is the primary key
- (A_ID, B_ID) is a foreign key that references AB(A_ID, B_ID)
- C_ID is a foreign key that references C(ID)